# Using AVPlayer for the iPhone, SeekToTime only ever restarts the video for me

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, video, avplayer

I am trying to get a fairly short video (0.05 seconds) to play from 0.02 seconds. I use the code below:

```
CMTime tolerance = CMTimeMake(0,1);
CMTime replayBeginTime = CMTimeMake(1, 50);

[player seekToTime: replayBeginTime toleranceBefore: tolerance toleranceAfter: tolerance];
[player play];
```

Where player is an AVPlayer*. The video plays fine from start to finish and then i hit a button to go back to roughly the half way point and it should play from there, but every time it just restarts the video.

I'm not a 100% sure I'm using CMTimeMake correctly.

Any help figuring out what I'm doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try kCMTimeZero perhaps? That is what the documentation references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating a CMTime with a value of 1/50 = 0.02, so you are using CMTimeMake correctly. But I think maybe you should use CMTimeMakeWithSeconds instead. Because CMTimeMake can only take an integer value of seconds, while  CMTimeMakeWithSeconds can take a float.
You should use it like this.

```
CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.2, 1);
[player seekToTime:newTime];
```

Good luck.